# How to use integer radio buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, integer, radio-button

What is the simplest way to represent an integer attribute with a limited number of valid values as radio buttons?

How can I use the formhelper to achieve this? I only see examples that use string values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

```
   <%= form_for :model do |f| %>
    <% 1.upto(10) do |i| %>
      <%= f.radio_button :integer, i %> #integer is the model field
    <% end %> 
   <% end %>
```

or

```
<%= form_tag do %>
<% 1.upto(10) do |i| %>
  <%= radio_button_tag :name, i %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
<% (1..10).each do |value| %>
  <%= f.radio_button_tag(:method_name, value) %>
<% end %>
```

Where `(1..10)` might belong into the model as a constants. What also makes validations easier:

```
# in the model
FOOS = (1..10)
validates :foo, inclusion: { in: FOOS }

# in the view
<% Model::FOOS.each do |values| %>
  <%= f.radio_button_tag(:foo, value) %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

My way is to use an enum in your model. E.g the role field will be saved as number 0 if the role is investor, number 1 if the role is trader in my example.

You need to declare your enum in your model .rb file like this:

```
enum role: [:investor,:trader]
```

Then in the view file:

```
 <%= f.radio_button :role, :investor , class: 'form-control underlined' %>
 <%= label :role_investor, 'I wanna be an investor' %>
 <%= f.radio_button :role, :trader  , class: 'form-control underlined' %>
 <%= label :role_trader, 'I wanna be a trader' %>
```